# Micronaut AWS Lambda Injected Dependencies NULL

Tags: java, aws-lambda, micronaut

We created a Lambda with Micronaut AWS.

The Handler looks like this:

```java
@Singleton
public class ValidationRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<S3Event, Integer> {
  @Inject private MessageService messageService;

  @Override
  public Integer execute(S3Event input) {
    messageService.init();
    [...]
  }
}
```

The MessageService class like this:

```java
@Singleton
public class MessageService {

    private final SnsClient client;

    @Inject
    public MessageService(SnsClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void init() {
       [...]
    }
}
```

Upon invoking the Lambda we get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Where the `NullPointerException` results from calling `messageService.init()`. Further debugging confirmed that `messageService` is indeed `null`.

So what are we missing here?

The project's `gradle.build` looks as follows:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.library") version "1.3.4"
}

version = "1.0.0"
group = "our.project.group"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    micronautAwsVersion = '2.4.0'
    junitVersion = '5.7.1'
    awsSdkVersion = '2.16.14'
    lambdaVersion = '1.2.1'
    lambdaEventsVersion = '3.7.0'
    mockitoVersion = '3.8.0'
}

micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("our.project.group.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")
    implementation group: 'io.micronaut.aws', name: 'micronaut-aws-sdk-v2', version: micronautAwsVersion
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-lambda-java-events', version: lambdaEventsVersion
    implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 'sns', version: awsSdkVersion

    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: junitVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: junitVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes (
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect {it.getName()}.join(' ')
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    dirMode = 0777
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the project uses lombok, as well as mapstruct. For simplicity, I omitted them from the `gradle.build`.

Comment: Not related to your problem but just FYI... I think the `@Inject` annotation on your `MessageService` constructor is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Use should consider making injection through constructor, that is recommended way for GraalVM native applications.

```
@Singleton
public class ValidationRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<S3Event, Integer> {
  
  private final MessageService messageService;

  @Inject 
  public ValidationRequestHandler(MessageService messageService) {
     this.messageService = messageService;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer execute(S3Event input) {
    messageService.init();
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: AWS uses default constructor of the class, so this injection is also not possible inside Micronaut Lambda, and this code will fail on aws lambda.

Comment: It works just fine in AWS Lambda, I am running it myself.
`public class Aws
        extends AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime<Request, Response, Request, Response> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new AwsLambdaRuntime().run(args);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    protected RequestHandler<Request, Response> createRequestHandler(String... args) {
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(ValidationRequestHandler.class);
    }
}`